# onclick - anonymous function vs defined vs html onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I need to create a link in element and then bind it with function. In example close button for message panel.

Which solution is best and why? I mean performance/standard. Or maybe there is something else which is even better:

1.
Defined function + onclick function called in anonymous

```
function add-close-button( ){
  $( '.msg' ).append( '<a href="#" class="close">Close me</a>' );
  $( '.msg .close' ).click( function(){ close-msg( ); } );
}
function close-msg( ){ /* code here */ }
```

2.
Defined function + html onclick

```
function add-close-button( ){
  $( '.msg' ).append( '<a href="#" class="close" onclick="close-msg">Close me</a>' );
}
function close-msg( ){ /* code here */ }
```

3.
Close function not defined, just anonymous onclick function

```
function add-close-button( ){
  $( '.msg' ).append( '<a href="#" class="close">Close me</a>' );
  $( '.msg .close' ).click( function(){ /* code here */ } );
}
```

Comment: use code formatting for code

Comment: FIxed. I did it first time but whem I added some comments to make post more clear it crash. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For #1 - Adding more named functions clutters up the global namespace. It's not a big thing, but it causes more "scanning" of the global namespace when you call something globally. Another incentive to namespace everything using a dummy object (e.g. var namespace = {};)

For #2 - Using an "onclick" handler in your HTML is blending your actual implementation of code with your presentation, which is considered a bit "old hat" and it's more difficult to see in your JS files where that event is bound, readable code is good.

For #3, if you just want that specific handler, with no reuse, it's quick and decouples yourself from the HTML. If you need to do subsequent binding, you have to jump through more hoops as the anonymous function is assigned directly to the handler and doesn't live anywhere else in the code.

If you want a more complex and dynamic use, case, you could use jQuery.on to do delegated event binding (again with an anonymous function).

See my quick demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0re6mgru/1/) using delegated eventing.

HTML:

```
<div id="myContent">
    <a href="#" class="close">Close me</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="#" class="showClose">Trigger the Close button appearing</a> 
</div>
```

Script:

```
$( "#myContent" ).on("click", ".close", function() {
  alert("clicked");
});

$( "#myContent" ).on("click", ".showClose", function() {
  $(".close").toggle();   
});
```

CSS:

```
.close {
   display:none;   
}
```

Comment: In that case what will be your solution/code for it? Creating a element in JS then add attributes and append it? So there will be no html?

Comment: Thanks, but I got the "on" even binding idea. I was thinking that you said my append method is old hat. It need to be added by script because all script is not html but rendered in JS.